# Single Sign-on - PingFederate (PF) - How to uncheck WS-Trust?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, pingfederate

Currently in Server Settings -> Roles and Protocols, WS-Trust is checked but it grayed out.  What is checked and uncheckable is:

```
 Enabled IdP
   SAML 2.0
 Enable IdP Discovery role
```

How do I uncheck WS-Trust?

Comment: You've opened a ticket for this (and a few others) now. Curious... Why do you want to uncheck it? Does it matter?

Comment: I'm just trying to simply things to determine where I am having a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't uncheck something is most commonly because it is in use. We won't let you disable a role that is in use by the product (because that would break a connection, and we don't want you to do that). You'll need to delete any connection that is using the WS-Trust STS before you can disable the role.

As a side note, out of courtesy to our support engineers, please do not open a ticket with them and then ask here on SO... I'm answering this here only so others can find the solution if they are looking for it.